# Dolphin/Konqueror wrong file type recognition

Tags: linux, mime-types, dolphin-file-manager

In Dolphin/Konqueror files that are supposed to have "unknown" file type have "Microsoft Help Attribute Definition File" as their type.

This also affect files without extension with special symbols in them(such as ^[[2J^[[0;0f I have at the begnning of .xsession-errors), swapfile, softlinks(to those files + dangling links).

In System Settings/File associations  "Microsoft Help Attribute Definition File" is a description for "application/octet-stream" type(see octet-stream.xml below).

It seems that they use it like some sort of fallback or default entry, because when I enter directory all of the files(not directories) for a few moments have this type(non-recognized?).
Problem is specific to those file browsers, I installed Thunar, Tux Commander, Double Commander  and they work fine. Files itself are okay:

```
[ ~]$ file .xsession-errors
.xsession-errors: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators, with escape sequences
[ ~]$ file --mime-type .xsession-errors
.xsession-errors: text/plain
[ ~]$ file link
link: broken symbolic link to 43399594
```

Tried to spot this type files, found some in ~/.local/share/mime/ but any changes(with subsequent update-desktop-database  update-mime-database calls and even reboot) gave nothing.

Thought that it may be due to wine office 2010 installation so erased wine mime, desktop and so files(link limit, you may find it on wine FAQ page under "4.3. How do I clean the Open With List?")  to no avail. Then deleted wine prefix - same result.
Wasn't able to find anything with google either (most of the problems there related to wrong application starting and not file type recognition).

Tested on a new user - all work like a charm. From there my .xsession-errors have type "unknown"

According to [bug 337708](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337708) seems that it related to shared-mime-info. Didn't find anything specific.

```
octet-stream.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-type xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info" type="application/octet-stream">
  <!--Created automatically by update-mime-database. DO NOT EDIT!-->
  <comment>Microsoft Help Attribute Definition File</comment>
  <glob-deleteall/>
  <glob pattern="*.bin"/>
  <glob pattern="*.hxd"/>
  <glob pattern="*.hxh"/>
  <glob pattern="*.hxi"/>
  <glob pattern="*.hxq"/>
  <glob pattern="*.hxr"/>
  <glob pattern="*.hxs"/>
  <glob pattern="*.hxw"/>
</mime-type>
```

[few pictures with dolphin, thunar, master-fast-print-screen while folder was loading](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b2izozpfylgxr20/AACSH-mKRAKY7ts8XXSSgo1ya?dl=0)

```
[ ~]$ uname -a
Linux Erefan 3.17.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 7 23:43:32 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux KDE 
[ ~]$ dolphin --version
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.3
Dolphin: 4.14.3
```

p.s. .xsession-errors used just as an example, actually many files have that wrong type.

---

**Edit 1:** After additional testing on new user I concluded that it is related to wine office 2010 installation. Specifically this installation put new octet-stream.xml file in ~/.local/share/mime/application/ which overrides the original one in /usr/share/mime/application/ . Actually installation provide application-octet-stream.xml in packages folder which is then used by update-mime-database to generate octet-stream.xml. Original file actually define "unknown" type of file. I'm not very familiar with syntax but it looks like there is nothing special. So I manually modified the application-octet-stream.xml to comply with the original + added icon(see below). So far all work just fine.

So if you want to try steps are as follows:

**Check all by yourself in case anything happens you'll be the one to blame.**

```
1. modify ~/.local/share/mime/packages/application-octet-stream.xml (see below).

2. run "update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/".

3. probably restart current session.
```

> application-octet-stream.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="application/octet-stream">
        <comment>unknown</comment>
        <icon name="unknown"/>
        <glob pattern="*.hxd"/>
        <glob pattern="*.hxh"/>
        <glob pattern="*.hxi"/>
        <glob pattern="*.hxq"/>
        <glob pattern="*.hxr"/>
        <glob pattern="*.hxs"/>
        <glob pattern="*.hxw"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Next step - xml files have ugly windows icon(seems that office installation is the one to blame 
) and I wonder why it doesn't change through normal File Associations settings.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: basically all files that are supposed to be of "unknown" type  now have "Microsoft Help Attribute Definition File" type
[dropbox with example](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b2izozpfylgxr20/AACSH-mKRAKY7ts8XXSSgo1ya?dl=0)

Comment: The title and question talk about a filetype association that is being used but should not.  The bug reference talks about Dolphin failing to recognize filetypes (opposite problem).  Have you looked in System Settings | File Associations?  See if this is useful for extracting the magic number info: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file

Comment: @fixer1234, hopefully clarified it a bit. Thanks for "magic", will research a bit later. That bug reference there is not for nothing but solely to state that "Shared mime info" is used in kde in comparison to "file"(don't know whether they are related or not though).
p.s System Settings | File Associations info is already there - octet-stream.xml file

Comment: This question is a "strange locution of the facts".  You say the filetype "should be" unknown.  There is really no such "should be unknown".  There are very few files that don't have any characteristics that make them recognizable as something, even if that is part of a broad generic class.  Your issue is that "Microsoft Help Attribute Definition File" is the name given to "application/octet-stream", which is apparently what those files are.  What would you like to call "application/octet-stream"?  Is the goal to rename that as "unknown"?

Comment: Dandling links, swapfile, files with unicode text(as "file" stated) for sure are not "Microsoft Help Attribute Definition File". I think it's obvious but I checked it on new user and any of them have "unknown"/link type. Plus checked files in my directory - all have proper file type (unknown, link).

Comment: There are a number of filetypes that are "application/octet-stream".  They are not unknown, they are recognized as "application/octet-stream".  The name of an application that uses a filetype is often assigned, even though it may not be universal.  You're looking for a way to remove the application association.

Comment: Your point stands to reason and I agree with it but the main problem is that there is no application (why would there? After all I installed only office). So basically it just renamed file type and nothing more. Therefore I'd like to return it back to normal(now this word feels ambiguous). On windows it may be correct association(not in all cases but hopefully most) but on Linux I have many "octet-stream" files that obviously cannot be opened even if I had an appropriate program(Microsoft help?). Thus this is not even an error but misunderstanding because I installed windows program on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I can see now I was a bit narrow-minded and obsessed with the idea that it's completely wrong.